# sql server 2008 select query condition using current date for date format 2014-11-06

Tags: php, sql

I am using SQL server 2008 i want to select the current date using SQL query i tried a lot.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [eve_id] FROM [dbMS].[ms].[eve_info] where eve_date = GETDATE()
```

i used this above sql query but it is showing blank page in sql query field

Comment: What data type is your `column_date`?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I want to fetch current date from table using SQL query.

Comment: data type in one table like "date" other i have "nvarcharmax"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GETDATE() works fine for me, you should test with your query

Comment: Thanks, but i used this query and changed the datatype as "date"."SELECT TOP 1000 [eve_id] FROM [dbMS].[ms].[eve_info] where eve_date = GETDATE()" . query shows blank page but i have current date like "2014-09-18"

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column_date = GETDATE()
```

This will return date in the format of "2014-09-18".

The problem may have been the space you left before the opening parenthesis after CURRENT_DATE.

Alternatively, your column_date column may be formatted weirdly. What is the field type (e.g INT, LONG, DATE, etc)?

Comment: Thanks for your response. but my question is GETDATE() supports datatype "date" and "nvarcharmax"?. because i am using this both.

Comment: if i use GETDATE() function sql server showing the error like The conversion of a nvarchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

Comment: Seems like your column_name is incorrect then. It should be of the DATE type.

The error is almost certainly due to the code trying to compare the output of GETDATE() with column_date, and column_date not being in the right format (e.g. a date).

Comment: Thanks, but i used this query and changed the datatype as "date"."SELECT TOP 1000 [eve_id] FROM [dbMS].[ms].[eve_info] where eve_date = GETDATE()" . query shows blank page but i have current date like "2014-09-18"

Comment: Perhaps the problem isn't in the SQL then. I'd suggest asking a new question with the entirety of the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you eve_date is of `DATE` OR `DATETIME` then following sql will do for you.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [eve_id] FROM [dbMS].[ms].[eve_info] where Datediff(dd,eve_date,GETDATE())=0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. i am getting the result